# Garbage in the end of `NSString` on xCode after `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange` method call

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I use the following code to replace an extension of a file:

```
NSString *fileOriginal = [url lastPathComponent];
NSString *fileSource = @"";
NSRange range = [fileOriginal rangeOfString:@"." options:NSBackwardsSearch];
if (range.length > 0) {
    range.length = fileOriginal.length - range.location;
    fileSource = [fileOriginal stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@".%@", @"cpp"]];
} else {
    fileSource = [fileOriginal stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@".%@", gFileExtension]];
}
```

The code works fine. But debugger shows garbage in the end of `NSString`:

[image]

The same result if I tried to add `retain` to strings. What's hell happens?

Comment: Where is your definition of `gFileExtension`?

Comment: If you stop at a breakpoint and do `po fileSource` you will see the proper output. I've seen this bizarre garbage too when viewing values in the variable view.

Comment: `gFileExtension` is define @"cpp"

Comment: I've had the same problem happen to me with stringByDeletingPathExtension... thanks all for asking/responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your definition of `gFileExtension` is valid, why not try this:

```
NSString *fileSource;
if ([[fileOriginal pathExtension] length] > 0)
{
    fileSource = [[fileOriginal stringByDeletingPathExtension] stringByAppendingPathExtension:gFileExtension];
}
else
{
    fileSource = [fileOriginal stringByAppendingPathExtension:gFileExtension];
}
```

Using the path handling built into `NSString`, you don't have to worry about the dot; it's done for you.

Comment: Can't look into it for you just now (out with the wife) but my guess is that your range's length may have something to do with it.

Comment: range.position = 12, range.length = 3, replaceFrom = @".cp", replaceTo = @".cpp", replaceWhere = @"Hello, World.cp"

Comment: I can't explain this one. I've discovered that, whether I provide a regular NSString instance containing "Hello, World.cp", or create a URL with that file name in it (space following the comma escaped, of course), sometimes the garbage appears, and sometimes it doesn't. But in any case, printing out the value shows that it is indeed the correct value. Perhaps it's a display quirk in the debugger.